# What happened to the Tullys in Riverun?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the episode No One, Jaime Lannister persuades (intimidates?) Edmure Tully to return to castle Riverun and order his vassals within to surrender, which they do despite the warden Brnyden (the Blackfish) Tully's protests.

This is depicted as a nonviolent resolution, but what becomes of the Tullys afterward? I highly doubt the Lannisters will just let the Tullys stay there, and Brynden pretty much spat on Brienne's offer that would have granted them safe passage to Sansa's forces- where did they go?

Comment: In the books, Brynden escaped...

Answer (score 3):

In the last episode of season 6, *The Winds of Winter*, Lord Walder Frey says to Ser Jaime:

> Edmure is back in a cell. Can't go killing my son-by-law, it wouldn't
>   be right. Give the family a bad name. … So, the famous Blackfish killed
>   by foot soldiers, eh? Legendary warrior, everyone said.

So: Lord Edmure is back in Lord Frey's dungeons, and Brynden is dead.

Comment: OK, but what about the other Tullys? Does Lord Frey have a dungeon big enough to ho;d all of them?

Comment: @Nu'Daq the Tully soldiers? I expect they're still following their Lord's orders, whether he's around or not. Nothing is said of them, though. Other than that, I don't think any nobility of House Tully is left alive.

Comment: @Nu'Daq - The head of the house told them to turn in their weapons, and he surrendered the castle. His obstinate uncle who was holding out was killed as a result. Disarmed and without any members of the actual family looking to lead them in a battle, I'm guessing they aren't viewed as any kind of a threat.

Comment: Still I'm pretty sure there's not enough room for vassals of the Lannisters, Freys *and* Tullys- they have to go somewhere.

Comment: @Nu'Daq The Tully soldiers aren't Tullys. The Tullys are all dead except for Edmure who is in a cell. The soldiers would probably be released or choose to server their *new* lords: the Freys.

Comment: @SystemDown- Ah. Did not know that.

Comment: I wonder what happened to him now... after the events of S7E1

Comment: @Skooba Very good question - but bear in mind that we met Lannister soldiers in S07E01 that were heading to deal with the situation with the Freys - I imagine their ally's prisoner would be kept a prisoner by the Lannister occupation unless the Frey daughters released him before they arrived.